# using lock in property with DataMember attribute

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using property like this in multithreading application (WCF service hosted in windows managed service):

```
private object lockObj = new object();
private string val = string.Empty;

[DataMember]
public string Value
{
    get 
    {
        lock(lockObj)
        {
            return val;
        }
    }
    set 
    {
        lock(lockObj)
        {
            val = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Sending via WCF service fails until I remove the locks, then it works. (don't have current exception, service fails without loging to my tracking)

Is there possibility to solve it with having locks, or I must to convert it to some reduced object without locks?

Comment: The locks don't really do anything.

Comment: the lock is unnecessary.

Comment: Why do you think you need the locks?

Comment: whatever the "service fails" problem is, it looks **very** unlikely to be related to these locks, unless you have "leaked" lockObj out and something else is competing on it. But as already stated: a lock for the duration of a string swap doesn't do much - a reference swap is already atomic. More useful in some other scenarios, but: I suspect you're using `lock` quite wrongly...

Comment: thx guys, but the string value is just for simplicity, my false... real type is a List<string>. Is the lock still unnecessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as I get no answer, I write my own solution.

as I write in comments, type of Value property is `List<string>` (later changed to `List<SomeMyObject>`) and when I remove locks, I got exceptions because of collection is modified. Then I make a method, which makes a DeepCopy of my list and what I send through WCF is Skelet version (from all inner objects I take just Ids) of previous object:

```
    public Skelet ToSkelet()
    {
        var result = new Skelet
        {
            Waiting = Waiting.DeepClone().ConvertAll(x => x.Id),
            Open = Open.DeepClone().ConvertAll(x => x.Id),
            Finished = Finished //this one is int
        };

        return result;
    }
```

on SO found DeepClone method:

```
    public static T DeepClone<T>(this T obj)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;

            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
```